# How to get SpatialGridDataFrame dimensions?

Tags: r

I use hyper<-readGDAL("test.bsq") to read an ENVI hdr file. This goes fine.
If I print(hyper) then I get this nice info

```
class       : SpatialGridDataFrame 
dimensions  : 619, 192, 118848, 101  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.173, 0.173  (x, y)
```

The information is all correct, the data contains 101 bands with 619x192 pixels. If I try dim(hyper) I only get the ncell, which is the total number of cells.
So, how do I get these dimensions which or obviously stored somewhere, since they are viewable through print() ?

Comment: `summary(hyper)` will give what you want?

Comment: No, I want to get the 619 and 192 values in some kind of variable. Summary only does the statistics for each band. I can see the 619 and 192 with print(), but I need to use them in other functions.